# Dotnet watch on macOS gives curl an tlsv1 alert protocol version error

Tags: asp.net, .net, macos, f#

I am developing an Asp.Net application on MacOS with F# (.NET 6.0.301). While writing code I run a `dotnet watch`:

```
dotnet watch run -v --project Server/Server.fsproj
```

and send a `curl` message to one of the api endpoints of the server

```
curl -k -i -d "@loginInfo.json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -v 'https://localhost:5001/services/IAdminApi/login'

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:5001...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5001 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
[...] // More handshake data
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

which returns the expected result. It worked seamessly until a few months ago, when I started to receive the following error

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:5001...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5001 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1404B42E:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:tlsv1 alert protocol version
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1404B42E:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

However, when I run the server directly **without** the `watch` command:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet Server/bin/Debug/net6.0/Server.dll
```

everything works perfectly, and the API sends back the proper info. The server uses a self-signed certificate that is read from file.

Everything is running locally in a macOS machine. I have tried in two machines with different macOS versions, and problems started after updating to Monterey 12.6 and Ventura 13. Now both machines run updated versions (Monterey 12.6.2 and Ventura 13.1), but the problem persists.
However, `dotnet watch` works as expected in Windows 10. Codes are run from a terminal, without any intervention from the IDE (Rider in my case). Even though I lean towards something at the os level, also tried sending the `curl` command with  the `--tlsv1.x --tls-max 1.x` options (x=0,1,2,3) with no luck. The version of `curl` is 7.79.1.

Any pointer to keep investigating will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think that that might be something related to how the dotnet watch command handles encrypted traffic. as per this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-watch

*"As part of dotnet watch, the browser refresh server mechanism reads this value to determine the WebSocket host environment. The value 127.0.0.1 is replaced by localhost, and the http:// and https:// schemes are replaced with ws:// and wss:// respectively."*

So perhaps while the https traffic (when you run the application without dotnet watch) works fine because it uses appropriate cyphers and version of TLS, there is a bug or some omission in the implementation of the wss protocol, where TLS is fixed to version 1.

It would appear that you have two options.

- run your application on local host without https
- configure your operating system to allow for TLS 1.0

Comment: I switched from https to http when using dotnet watch, as suggested and works fine. Adding up to the problem, the `dotnet watch` **with** https runs perfect exactly one time after login in my computer, but got the problem back when dotnet watch needs to rebuild something.